# EnqueueNDRangeKernel returns Invalid Kernel Args when everything is successful?

Tags: opencl

I have 26 kernel arguments that I am setting in the same exact manner that I have done for multiple programs now, but EnqueueNDRangeKernel will no longer run and tells me I am passing incorrect kernel arguments. The code is below followed by the results I get from running the code.

```
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Q1cl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg Q1: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&NtoFcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg NtoFcl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&FtoNcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg FtoNcl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Drcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg Drcl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Dscl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg Dscl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&mapRcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg mapR: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 6, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&fQ1);
errCheck("Kernel Arg fQ1: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 7, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&ffQ1);
errCheck("Kernel Arg ffQ1: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 8, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&F1);
errCheck("Kernel Arg F1: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 9, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&G1);
errCheck("Kernel Arg G1: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 10, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dQ1);
errCheck("Kernel Arg dQ1: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 11, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dQ1dr);
errCheck("Kernel Arg dQ1dr: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 12, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dQ1ds);
errCheck("Kernel Arg dQ1dr: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 13, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dQ1dx);
errCheck("Kernel Arg dQ1dx: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 14, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dQ1dy);
errCheck("Kernel Arg dQ1dy: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 15, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&sxcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg sxcl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 16, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&sycl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg sycl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 17, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&rxcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg rxcl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 18, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&rycl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg rycl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 19, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&nxcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg nxcl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 20, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&nycl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg nycl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 21, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&fluxQ1);
errCheck("Kernel Arg flux: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 22, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&resQ1cl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg resQ1: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 23, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Fscalecl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg Fscalecl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 24, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&rk4bcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg rk4bcl: ", err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 25, sizeof(cl_double), (void*)&dtcl);
errCheck("Kernel Arg dtcl: ", err);

for(i=0;i<device_counter;++i){
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[i], kernel, 2, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
    errCheck("EnqeuedNDRangeKernel device ", err);
}
```

And the resultant output is:

```
Q1 buffer:: Success
resQ1 buffer:: Success
NtoF Buffer:: Success
FtoN Buffer:: Success
Dr Buffer:: Success
Ds Buffer:: Success
Sx Buffer:: Success
Sy Buffer:: Success
rx Buffer:: Success
ry Buffer:: Success
Nx Buffer:: Success
Ny Buffer:: Success
mapR buffer:: Success
Fscale Buffer:: Success
fQ1 Buffer:: Success
ffQ1 Buffer:: Success
F1 Buffer:: Success
G1 Buffer:: Success
dQ1 Buffer:: Success
dQ1dr Buffer:: Success
dQ1dr Buffer:: Success
rk4b Buffer:: Success
Kernel Arg Q1: : Success
Kernel Arg NtoFcl: : Success
Kernel Arg FtoNcl: : Success
Kernel Arg Drcl: : Success
Kernel Arg Dscl: : Success
Kernel Arg mapR: : Success
Kernel Arg fQ1: : Success
Kernel Arg ffQ1: : Success
Kernel Arg F1: : Success
Kernel Arg G1: : Success
Kernel Arg dQ1: : Success
Kernel Arg dQ1dr: : Success
Kernel Arg dQ1dr: : Success
Kernel Arg sxcl: : Success
Kernel Arg sycl: : Success
Kernel Arg rxcl: : Success
Kernel Arg rycl: : Success
Kernel Arg nxcl: : Success
Kernel Arg nycl: : Success
Kernel Arg flux: : Success
Kernel Arg resQ1: : Success
Kernel Arg Fscalecl: : Success
Kernel Arg rk4bcl: : Success
Kernel Arg dtcl: : Success
EnqeuedNDRangeKernel: : Invalid kernel arguments
```

I am so lost as to why EnqueueNDRange is angry. The results used to include an invalid arg size for dt

```
Kernel Arg dtcl: : Invalid argument size
```

but after moving it to the bottom of the argument calls the error went away. Really weird behavior.

Additionally I have tried running the program with only one kernel argument and it still gave me the error, then I ran it without kernel arguments and EnqueueNDRangeKernel returned CL_SUCCESS.

EDIT: Here's the header for the kernel

```
__kernel void clAxBtrans(__global double* Q1,
                     __global double* NtoF,
                     __global double* FtoN,
                     __global double* Dr,
                     __global double* Ds,
                     __global int* mapR,
                    __global double* fQ1,
                    __global double* ffQ1,
                    __global double* F1,
                    __global double* G1,
                    __global double* dQ1,
                    __global double* dQ1dr,
                    __global double* dQ1ds,
                    __global double* dQ1dx,
                    __global double* dQ1dy,
                    __global double* sx,
                    __global double* sy,
                    __global double* rx,
                    __global double* ry,
                    __global double* nx,
                    __global double* ny,
                    __global double* fluxQ1,
                    __global double* resQ1,
                    __global double* Fscale,
                    __global double* rk4b
this stupid thing-->  __global double* newQ1, double dt)
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post the kernel function, or least the function header.
You say you have 25 arguments, but I count 26 (0-25). And in the output, only 24 are successful.
The problem are these two:

```
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 13, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dQ1dx);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 14, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dQ1dy);
```

Also your output is wrong for

```
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 12, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&dQ1ds);
errCheck("Kernel Arg dQ1dr: ", err);
```

It should be `errCheck("Kernel Arg dQ1ds: ", err);`

Most likely your problem is a mix-up in the parameter order, thus resulting in invalid kernel argument sizes in a non-intuitive manner (since some will have the correct size, some won't). If you post the kernel function header, we should be able to sort this out.

Comment: Sorry about that, meant I had 26, accidentally said 25 because I saw the number. The kernel header has been added. Thank you for spotting that dQ1dx and dQ1dy aren't even present in the success outputs, I'll definitely take a look there and see what I find.

Comment: When posting the kernel I noticed that my header had an extra __global double* call that I had meant to remove but forgot to.  Now it's fixed and the code functions.  I'm still confused though because it occured even prior to adding the extra call. Regardless, thank you for pointing out something that I completely missed, and that was completely trivial T_T